# difference between spark.executor.memoryOverhead and spark.memory.offHeap.size

Tags: apache-spark, memory, jvm

when I search off-heap in [Spark configuration](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.5/configuration.html), there are two properties related(`spark.executor.memoryOverhead` and `spark.memory.offHeap.size`), I am not sure the relationship between these two.

If I enable `spark.memory.offHeap.enabled`, will `spark.memory.offHeap.size` be part of `spark.executor.memoryOverhead`? or these two types of off-heap memory are independent(thus the total off-heap memory is the sum of the two)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [spark off heap memory config and tungsten](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43330902/spark-off-heap-memory-config-and-tungsten)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See my full answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61723456/6470969

Short answer: as of current Spark version (2.4.5), if you specify `spark.memory.offHeap.size`, you should also add this portion to `spark.executor.memoryOverhead`. E.g. you set `spark.memory.offHeap.size` to 500M and you have `spark.executor.memory=2G`, then the default `spark.executor.memoryOverhead` is `max(2*0.1, 384)=384M`, but you'd better to increase the `memoryOverhead` to `384M+500M=884M`.